# Custom capitalize a string using a regex

Tags: jquery, regex, uppercase, capitalize

Let's say my textarea has this string:

> it is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted. by the
>   readable content of a page when looking at its layout.the point of
>   using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of
>   letters,as opposed to using.

I want to custom capitalize this string when the user is typing in the textarea.

- To uppercase first character
- To lowercase other characters
- Uppercase the after dot character
- Force to add a **space character** after dot and comma.

The output string should be like this:

> **İ**t is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted. **B**y the
>   readable content of a page when looking at its layout. **T**he point of
>   using **l**orem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of
>   letters, as opposed to using.

How can I do this and with what kind of [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)?

Comment: How can one be able to identity that "Lorem" should be turned lowercase ? Words following a period, should be capitalized. But what is the criteria by which Lorem should be not ? Unless you can define a rule, you will not be able to have the code do something you yourself do not know how to

Comment: I already wrote the criterias. First char would be upper case. and lower case all other chars except after dot char.

Comment: In your formatted example, you did not single out in bold the letters you want capitalized, only ? A bit confusing.

Comment: @Veverke yes, First chat will be uppercase and other chars will be lowercase. Except after dot first char.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the solution you want, but for a start, you could use:

```
var text = 'it is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted. by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.the point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters,as opposed to using.';
var r = /\.\s?/;
var sentences = text.split(r);
var desiredResult = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
    if (sentences[i].length > 0) {
        var fixedSentence = sentences[i][0].toUpperCase() + sentences[i].substr(1).toLowerCase();
        if (i > 0 && sentences[i][0] != ' ')  {
            fixedSentence = ' ' + fixedSentence;
        }

        desiredResult.push(fixedSentence);
        console.log(fixedSentence);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i; add space after dot and comma, if there is no space